# Create an icon like pubg to move a character in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface

Iam pretty new to Flutter and Dart progamming.
I wanted to create an icon from which we can move a character.

[image]

Something like this. The middle circle should be slidable and there should be listeners attached which can be triggered when the circle is on top of that button.

Is it possible in flutter?
If yes please provide me with some details.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **`Stack`** widget to achieve this

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Phone Number InputFormatter'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
            child: Center(
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned(
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    child: Icon(Icons.home),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    child: Icon(Icons.home),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    top: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    child: Icon(Icons.home),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    child: Icon(Icons.home),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    top: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    child: Icon(Icons.home),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you this is cool. But how do I make the middle icon to slide to top, left, bottom, and right?

Comment: For that you can use Draggable widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html @MOHAMMEDNUMAN